# How does ftell affect a binary file being read in mode 'r' instead of 'rb'?

Tags: c, file, binary, cs50

I've a rather curious question, not very practical at all really. The error (reading a binary file in `r` mode) is in plain sight but I'm confused by something else.

Here's the code-

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdint.h>

#define BUFFER_LEN 512

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main()
{
    FILE* memcard = fopen("card.raw", "r");
    BYTE buffer[BUFFER_LEN];
    int count = 0;
    while (fread(buffer, sizeof(*buffer), BUFFER_LEN, memcard) != 0)
    {
        printf("count: %d\n", count++);
    }
    fclose(memcard);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, `card.raw` is a binary file, so this reading *will* go wrong due to being read in `r` mode instead of `rb`. But what I'm curious about is that, that loop executes exactly 3 times, in the final execution, it doesn't even read 512 bytes.

Now if I change that loop to

```
while (fread(buffer, sizeof(*buffer), BUFFER_LEN, memcard) != 0)
{
    printf("ftell: %ld\n", ftell(memcard));
}
```

It no longer stops at 3 executions. In fact, it keeps going until (presumabely) the end of file. The `fread` count is still messed up. Many of the reads do not return 512 as elements read. But that is most probably due to the file being opened in `r` mode and all the encoding errors it's being accompanied with .

`ftell` shouldn't affect the file itself, then why does including `ftell` in the loop make it execute more times?

I decided to change the loop a bit more to extract more info-

```c
while ((count = fread(buffer, sizeof(*buffer), BUFFER_LEN, memcard)) != 0)
{
    printf("fread bytes read: %d\n", count);
    printf("ftell: %ld\n", ftell(memcard));
}
```

This loops just as many times as it would, provided `ftell` is included in the loop and the first few results look like-

[image: ftell results]

Now if I just remove that `ftell` line completely, it gives me-

[image: without ftell results]

Only 3 executions, yet nothing changed.

What's the explanation behind this behaviour?

Note: I know the counts returned by both `fread` and `ftell` are probably wrong due to the read mode, that's not my concern though. I'm only curious - why the difference, between including `ftell` and not including it.

Also, in case it helps, The `card.raw` file is actually just the cs50 pset4 "memory card". You can get it by `wget https://cdn.cs50.net/2019/fall/psets/4/recover/recover.zip` and storing the output file in a `.zip`

Edit: I should mention this was on windows and using clang tools for VS2019. The command line options (checked from VS2019 project properties) looked like-

```
/permissive- /GS /W3 "Debug\" "Debug\" /Zi /Od "Debug\vc142.pdb" /fp:precise /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /WX- /Gd /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\Test.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

Edit: Also, I did check for `ferror` inside the loop, with and without `ftell`, got no errors from it at all. In fact, `feof` returns 1 after the loop, in both cases.

Edit: I also tried adding a `memcard == NULL` check right after the `fopen`, same behaviour.

Edit: To address the answer by @orlp. I did, infact, check for errors. I should definitely have posted it though.

```c
while ((count = fread(buffer, sizeof(*buffer), BUFFER_LEN, memcard)) != 0)
{
    if ((err = ferror(memcard)))
    {           
        fprintf(stderr, "Error code: %d", err);
        perror("Error: ");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("fread bytes read: %d\n", count);
    printf("ftell: %ld\n", ftell(memcard));
}
if ((err = ferror(memcard)))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error code: %d", err);
    perror("Error: ");
    return 1;

}
```

Neither of the 2 `if` statements are ever triggered.

Edit: I thought we got the answer already, it was `ftell` resetting the EOF. But I changed the loop to-

```c
while ((count = fread(buffer, sizeof(*buffer), BUFFER_LEN, memcard)) != 0)
{
    if ((err = ferror(memcard)))
    {
        fclose(memcard);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error code: %d", err);
        perror("Error: ");
        return 1;
    }
    if (feof(memcard))
    {
        printf("reached before\n");
    }
    printf("fread bytes read: %d\n", count);
    ftell(memcard);
    if (feof(memcard))
    {
        printf("reached after\n");
    }
}
```

this triggers both the first `if(feof)` and the second `if(feof)`

As expected though, if I change the `ftell` to `fseek(memcard, 0, SEEK_CUR)`, the `EOF` *is* reset and the `reached after` is never printed.

Comment: When I tried your code, without the `ftell` (the code you show originally), it executes the loop 7313 times. I tried it on Ubuntu using `gcc`.

Comment: > Now, `card.raw` is a binary file, so this reading will go wrong due to being read in `r` mode instead of `rb`.
No it will not necessarily go wrong. That depends on your platform.

Comment: Yes I should mention it was on windows. Windows seems to have trouble with binary files in non binary mode

Comment: Could remove one of the _usual suspects_: Check `memcard != NULL`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica sorry, I dunno how it ended up there in the question. I did not use `&` in my testing, not to worry.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  What options?

Comment: @AndrewHenle just added that to the question, I'm using `clang` for VS2019, the options are just default VS2019 stuff

Comment: Also just checked `clang` from the command line, `clang ./test.c test.exe`, same behaviour

Comment: "ftell shouldn't affect the file itself, then why does including ftell in the loop make it execute more times?" --> Bug in compilation/library.

Comment: Just tested on linux with `gcc`, same behaviour across both and no weird `fread`s, it always reads 512 bytes. Wonder if it's `clang` or windows.

Comment: How does it behave if you add `setbuf( memcard, NULL );` after `fopen()`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle just tested, same behaviour. Looks like buffering is not the cause

Comment: "in the final execution, it doesn't even read 512 bytes." and "The fread count is still messed up." concern me in that the code `while (fread(buffer, sizeof(*buffer), BUFFER_LEN, memcard) != 0)` does not update `count` so these conclusions are based on something other than the posted code.  I recommend to post the exact code used at each step to improve the investigation.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Those statements are based on the code posted right after. Where `count` is updated according to the return value of `fread`

Comment: Without the `ftell`, it stops when it runs into a `0x1a` character which means EOF in Windows text-mode files. I don't know why calling `ftell` would change this.

Comment: @interjay Hmmm, very useful comment.

Comment: @interjay that makes a lot of sense. A friend suggested the same too, though they didn't know which exact character it was.

Comment: Curious,  Is `feof()` set after a short read?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it is!, I believe I mentioned that. `feof` is set in both cases, very strange.

Comment: I saw the "In fact, feof returns 1 __after__ the loop", wanted to see if code is looping after `feof()` is true. Is `ftell()`  incorrectly re-setting the end-of file flag?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica bingo! Just now I included `feof` inside the loop, and that's precisely it. I does get reached and `ftell` seems to reset it. So the combination of `0x1a` and `ftell` resetting it, that's the issue. Care to explain the entire thing in one answer?

Answer (score 5):

As some commentors pointed out, it ran into an `EOF`, and `ftell` actually got rid of that EOF. Why? To find the answer, we have to look inside glibc's source code. We can find the [source for `ftell`:](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/libio/ioftell.c):

```c
long int
_IO_ftell (FILE *fp)
{
  off64_t pos;
  CHECK_FILE (fp, -1L);
  _IO_acquire_lock (fp);
  pos = _IO_seekoff_unlocked (fp, 0, _IO_seek_cur, 0);
  if (_IO_in_backup (fp) && pos != _IO_pos_BAD)
    {
      if (_IO_vtable_offset (fp) != 0 || fp->_mode <= 0)
    pos -= fp->_IO_save_end - fp->_IO_save_base;
    }
  _IO_release_lock (fp);
  if (pos == _IO_pos_BAD)
    {
      if (errno == 0)
    __set_errno (EIO);
      return -1L;
    }
  if ((off64_t) (long int) pos != pos)
    {
      __set_errno (EOVERFLOW);
      return -1L;
    }
  return pos;
}
libc_hidden_def (_IO_ftell)

weak_alias (_IO_ftell, ftell)
```

This is the important line:

```c
pos = _IO_seekoff_unlocked (fp, 0, _IO_seek_cur, 0);
```

Let's find the [source for `_IO_seekoff_unlocked`](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/libio/ioseekoff.c):

```c
off64_t
_IO_seekoff_unlocked (FILE *fp, off64_t offset, int dir, int mode)
{
  if (dir != _IO_seek_cur && dir != _IO_seek_set && dir != _IO_seek_end)
    {
      __set_errno (EINVAL);
      return EOF;
    }

  /* If we have a backup buffer, get rid of it, since the __seekoff
     callback may not know to do the right thing about it.
     This may be over-kill, but it'll do for now. TODO */
  if (mode != 0 && ((_IO_fwide (fp, 0) < 0 && _IO_have_backup (fp))
            || (_IO_fwide (fp, 0) > 0 && _IO_have_wbackup (fp))))
    {
      if (dir == _IO_seek_cur && _IO_in_backup (fp))
    {
      if (_IO_vtable_offset (fp) != 0 || fp->_mode <= 0)
        offset -= fp->_IO_read_end - fp->_IO_read_ptr;
      else
        abort ();
    }
      if (_IO_fwide (fp, 0) < 0)
    _IO_free_backup_area (fp);
      else
    _IO_free_wbackup_area (fp);
    }

  return _IO_SEEKOFF (fp, offset, dir, mode);
}
```

Basically, it just does some checks then calls `_IO_SEEKOFF`, so [let's find its source](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/895ef79e04a953cac1493863bcae29ad85657ee1/libio/libioP.h#L181):

```c
/* The 'seekoff' hook moves the stream position to a new position
   relative to the start of the file (if DIR==0), the current position
   (MODE==1), or the end of the file (MODE==2).
   It matches the streambuf::seekoff virtual function.
   It is also used for the ANSI fseek function. */
typedef off64_t (*_IO_seekoff_t) (FILE *FP, off64_t OFF, int DIR,
                      int MODE);
#define _IO_SEEKOFF(FP, OFF, DIR, MODE) JUMP3 (__seekoff, FP, OFF, DIR, MODE)
```

So basically, `ftell` ends up calling a function which is the equivalent of `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR)`. And in the `fseek` standards we see: "A successful call to the `fseek()` function clears the end-of-file indicator for the stream." That's why `ftell` changes the behavior of the program.

Comment: Hmmm, as the C standard has no mention of `ftell()` clearing the _end-of-file indicator_, this appears to be non-compliant behavior.  The `fread()` call after a short read should return 0 as the _end-of-file indicator_ should still be set.

Comment: Interesting, it seems like `ftello` is allowed to reset the error on a file, but not `ftell`...?
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ftell.html

Comment: I do not find support for "ftello is allowed to reset the error on a file".  Both `ftello()` and `ftell()` can set `errno`, but that is not the _error indicator_ for the stream as reported by `ferror()`.  IAC, there is no implied ability for either function to clear the end-of-file indicator.

Comment: Bad news, `ftell` isn't resetting the EOF - I put another `if(feof(memcard))` after the `ftell`, and it still got triggered. `fread` is somehow continuing reading even after that "fake" EOF, We're back at square one..?

Answer (score 1):

`fread()` has

> The fread function returns the number of elements successfully read, which may be less than nmemb if a read error or end-of-file is encountered.

When `count < BUFFER_LEN`, OP reported `feof()` was true - as expected.

What is unexpected is that a following `fread()` returns non-zero.

IMO, a non-compliant library.

(OP reports new info, so this answer now incomplete.)

<strike>It appears `ftell()`, incorrectly IMO, reset the end-of-file indicator for the stream, allowing additional reads to occur.</strike>

Comment: Bad news, `ftell` isn't resetting the EOF - I put another `if(feof(memcard))` after the `ftell`, and it still got triggered. `fread` is somehow continuing reading even after that "fake" EOF, We're back at square one..?

Comment: @Chase "ftell isn't resetting the EOF" --> Well that is good as it should not do so.  C has "The byte input functions read characters from the stream as if by successive
calls to the fgetc function." so after a short `fread()`, the next `fread()` should return 0 as the that call is like 512 `fgetc()`.  And `fgetc()` has "**If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set**, or if the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file
indicator for the stream is set and the fgetc function returns EOF.  Curious, after a short `fread()`, what does `fgetc()` return? and then `feof(), ferror()`?

Comment: Without the `ftell`, i.e shortread at the 3rd iteration, `fgetc` returns -1, `ferror` is still 0 and `feof` is 1

Comment: with `ftell`, if I do `fgetc` *before* `ftell`, after a shortread it gives me -1, I do it after `ftell`, and suddenly no -1

Comment: With `ftell()`, what is `feof(), ferror()` before and after `fgetc()`?

Comment: `ferror` gives 0, `feof` gives 1, in all situations, before `ftell`, after `ftell`, before `fgetc` and after `fgetc`

Comment: Hmmm, `ftell()` is clearing _something_ and `fread()` is not compliant.  `fread()` should return 0 when `feof()` is true.  BTW, with "suddenly no -1", what was the value? 26?